# Project configurator "EnableJdtAptM" required by plugin execution "maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile" is not available

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I have no idea how to fix this. I imported a Maven project that actually hasn't anything to do with Spring but I am getting

> Project configurator "`org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.properties.editor.maven.EnableJdtAptM2EProjectConfigurator`" required by plugin execution "`org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile` (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)" is not available. To enable full functionality, install the project configurator and run Maven->Update Project Configuration.

Of course I already run a Maven update but it does not resolve this error.

So what is this even about?

Comment: Could you post your POM and the content of your Eclipse `.project`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try installing m2e-apt from Eclipse Marketplace (apt stands for Annotation Processing Tool) and then running Maven -> Update Project...

At least for me, this fixed the issue.

EDIT: m2e-apt is also available from jboss update site: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2e-extensions/m2e-apt

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Do you know why is this working, what causes this problem?

Comment: This problem is probably caused by some annotations in the source code that need to be processed but I can't really provide specific answer without knowing anything about the project. Eclipse has built-in support for annotations but maven projects need this m2e-apt plugin because compilation is handled by maven. Here are some links that provide further information.
 http://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder
 https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-apt
 https://immutables.github.io/apt.html

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with unknown causes and solved it by doing an "Update Maven Project": right-click the project name and select Maven > Update Maven Project (or just press Alt+F5)